# How to determine whether backend database is HANA DB?

Tags: abap, hana

There is requirement that if backend database is HANA DB the system trigger a update operation. otherwise the db is non-HANA db the system raises an error.

How to determine whether backend database is HANA DB in ABAP codes?

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `CL_DB_SYS=>DBSYS_TYPE` - if it is `HDB`, you're on a HANA system. Be sure to read the documentation of that attribute.

Comment: BTW,  SY-DBSYS also can be used to retrieve the db type.

Comment: Yes - read the documentation, CL_DB_SYS also tells you when you should care about it or rather when you should NOT attempt to go native, for example because you're in the middle of an upgrade...